# Django : <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7feaac2761d0> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am getting a problem in django serialization

Here is my model for the state

```
class State(models.Model):
    class Translation(translation.Translation):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    capital     = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name="state_capital", null=True)
    country     = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name="state_country", null=True)
    latitude    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, default=Decimal("0.0"))
    longitude   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6, default=Decimal("0.0"))
    code        = models.CharField(max_length=2)
```

Based on county_id i am filtering the states name and tried to convert in json format so that i can update the select box .

But  I am getting while doing this .

```
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x7feaac2761d0> is not JSON serializable
```

Here is my views .

```
def get_getstate(request):
    catid = request.GET['catid']
    get_related_subcategory = State.objects.filter(country_id = catid)

    json_models = serializers.serialize("json", get_related_subcategory)
    return HttpResponse(json_models, mimetype="application/javascript")
```

Please  help me outto solve this error .

**Update**

I also tried like this

```
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer as JSONSerializer
import decimal
import json
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            return '%.2f' % obj # Display Decimal obj as float
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


class DecimalSerializer(JSONSerializer):
    def end_serialization(self):
        self.options.pop('stream', None)
        self.options.pop('fields', None)
        json.dump(self.objects, self.stream, cls=DecimalEncoder, **self.options)
```

With this view

```
def get_getstate(request):
    catid = request.GET['catid']
    get_related_subcategory = State.objects.filter(country_id = catid)
    my_serializer = DecimalSerializer()
    print my_serializer.serialize(get_related_subcategory, indent=4)
```

Comment: you can use force_text.

Answer (score 19):

`django.utils.functional.__proxy__` object is a lazy translation. Django documentation says that  calling unicode() with the lazy translation as the argument will generate a Unicode string in the current locale (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#translated-strings). When the translation is done, serialization makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running an older version of `django` then you can't serialize `QuerySets` out-of-the-box. Try

```
json_models = serializers.serialize("json", list(get_related_subcategory))
```

It might also be worth checking that `get_related_subcategory` isn't empty. Which version of `django` are you running?

Comment: Ok, seconds given:, does the suggested change work?  ```>>> print (datetime.now() - datetime(2013,2,15,10,38))
843 days, 19:24:01.833422```